# HTML 5 Canvas toDATAURL always the same

Tags: html, canvas, base64

http://aaronhuzhang.com/html5draw/

When hit submit, the base64 url would display in your console.
somehow it is always the same.

Comment: Could you elaborate better your question? Some piece of code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting your code, I could see that you want a `jpeg`. By default, canvases are transparent, which makes requesting `.toDataURL()` (with no arguments) a breeze, as it gives you a `png` and pngs support transparency.

What happens is that when you request it as `image/jpeg`, the transparent parts have to be filled somehow, and that is with the black color. Because your stroke color is also black, the generated `jpeg` is a big black block, thus you get always the same base64.

If `jpeg` is really needed, I suggest you take a look at [this blog post](https://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2011/01/setting-the-background-color-when-generating-images-from-canvas-todataurl/). Otherwise just stick with the default `png` implementation.